# Why is my if statement is not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

Why the `if` statement in the bottom of my code does not work?
the words list contain several 'test', but the print statement below the `if` statement did not works.

```
text1 = "a"
text2 = "b"
text3 = "c"
words = []
if len(text1) < 2:
    words.append('test11')
elif text1.isspace():
    words.append('test12')
if len(text2) < 2:
    words.append('test21') 
elif text2.isspace():
    words.append('test22')
if len(text3) < 2:
    words.append('test31')
elif text3.isspace():
    words.append('test32')
if "test" in words:
    print "Test"
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is working fine. Nothing is printed because your list `words` does not contain the string `"test"`.

Comment: The list `words` does not contain the exact word `"test"`. May be you are confusing this with string

Comment: because `"test"` is not in `words`, it is in some of the words within `words`, but not `words` itself.  You could instead use: `if any(["test" in word for word in words])`. Although this is getting a bit wordy.

Comment: because your list `words = ['test11', 'test21', 'test31']`, not exactly `test` is there.

Comment: thank you for the help. I have solved the issue using for statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the end of your first 3 `if` statements you have:

```
words = ['test11', 'test21', 'test31']
```

By using `in` to check if `'test'` occurs within the array `words`, what it is actually doing is comparing `'test'` with each word in words:

```
'test11' == 'test'  # False
'test21' == 'test'  # False
'test31' == 'test'  # False
```

So clearly it should return `False`.  What you need to do is check if `'test'` appears within any of the words in `words`:

```
for word in words:
    if 'test' in word:
        print("Test")
        break
```

Or more pythonically:

```
if any(["test" in word for word in words]):
    print("Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something that test if the word`test` is inside the strings which are listed in your `words` list :

```
text1 = "a"
text2 = "b"
text3 = "c"
words = []
if len(text1) < 2:
    words.append('test11')
elif text1.isspace():
    words.append('test12')
if len(text2) < 2:
    words.append('test21') 
elif text2.isspace():
    words.append('test22')
if len(text3) < 2:
    words.append('test31')
elif text3.isspace():
    words.append('test32')
for i in words:
    if "test" in i:
        print "Test"
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

'test' itself is an complete string that is not present in the list, if you compare within the elements of the list it will be true.

```
validity = map(lambda x: 'test' in x, words)
if True in validity:
    print "Test"
```